# Can I make this JOIN using OR faster without using unions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL Server 2008 R2, is there a way to use some hints to force this query, which uses OR in a join, to run as fast as the below one, which replaces the OR with Unions?

**Slow query:**

```
select <stuff> from 
UPCs u
JOIN Ingredients i on 
(u.UPCID = i.UPCID) or ( u.CategoryID = i.CategoryID and u.Quality = i.Quality) or     (u.ManufacturerID = i.ManufacturerID and u.Quality = i.Quality)
```

**Faster query doing the same thing, but applying the criteria separately and concatenating the results with unions:**

```
select <stuff> from UPCs u join Ingredients i on 
(u.UPCID = i.UPCID)
UNION ALL
select <stuff> from UPCs u join Ingredients i on u.CategoryID = i.CategoryID and u.Quality =     i.Quality)
UNION ALL 
select <stuff> from UPCs u join Ingredients i on u.ManufacturerID = i.ManufacturerID and u.Quality = i.Quality
```

With the unions, it's doing a loop join on UPCs, and 2 hash joins, then concatenating the results of the union together. UPC ID is a clustered primary key, the other fields are non-indexed, and both tables are very large.

EDIT: Please note, I'm doing subsequent joins off of ingredients, so I'd happily break it up into multiple joins on ingredient, but only if it's even faster than the union. Real world query is something like this:

```
Select <stuff> from #UnknownPoursForThisEvent up
JOIN UPCs u on up.UPCID = u.UPCID
JOIN Tags t on t.TagNumber = up.TagNumber
JOIN Ingredients i on (i.UPCID = u.UPCID) or ( u.CategoryID = i.CategoryID and u.Quality =     i.Quality) or (u.ManufacturerID = i.ManufacturerID and u.Quality = i.Quality)
join Recipe r on i.RecipeID = r.RecipeID
join TicketItemAliases tia on tia.RecipeID = tia.RecipeID
<... Join, left join, and apply lots of other criteria>
```

EDIT2: Execution plans. http://imgur.com/eMzqPvL&zqQ6snz#1

Comment: Have you checked for missing indexes? i.e. reviewed the actual execution plan?

Comment: The answers to both of those questions are available in the original post; however, I'm not looking for database architecture advice, just whether there's a way to make SQL Server not take a foolish path to getting its results without using the unions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but worth giving it a go.....

```
SELECT <stuff> 
FROM       UPCs        u 
INNER JOIN Ingredients i  ON  i.UPCID = u.UPCID
LEFT  JOIN Ingredients i2 ON  u.CategoryID = i2.CategoryID 
                          AND u.Quality = i2.Quality
LEFT  JOIN Ingredients i3 ON  u.ManufacturerID = i3.ManufacturerID 
                          AND u.Quality = i3.Quality
```

Comment: I have tried the triple left join and it does run at the same speed as the union, but I'm joining even more tables on ingredients later on, so sadly, this'll end up being even uglier than using unions. I'll update the post to mention that I am joining on ingredients subsequently.

Comment: I cant see these left joins getting uglier than UNION ALLs anyway post your whole query, half a question will only give you half the answer.

Comment: Maybe use the triple join and then something like `JOIN Recipe r ON COALESCE(i.RecipeID,i2.RecipeID,i3.RecipeID) = r.RecipeID`. It's not really nice, but probably not as ugly as using unions. Might, however, come down to the same performance problem as the original Join?

Comment: You could also try to put `COALESCE(i.RecipeID,i2.RecipeID,i3.RecipeID) AS RecipeID` in the field list and then reference that on the join. Don't know whether that would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

logically

```
select <stuff> from 
UPCs u
  JOIN Ingredients i on 
       (u.UPCID = i.UPCID) or 
       (u.CategoryID = i.CategoryID and u.Quality = i.Quality) or
       (u.ManufacturerID = i.ManufacturerID and u.Quality = i.Quality)
```

Should be the same as this simplified version of

```
select <stuff> from 
UPCs u
  JOIN Ingredients i on 
       u.UPCID = i.UPCID or 
       (u.Quality = i.Quality And
       (u.CategoryID = i.CategoryID Or u.ManufacturerID = i.ManufacturerID))
```

but hey maybe the execution path will be different.

Comment: Worth a shot! So it didn't fix my problem, but it technically made the slow version a little faster... you are the 1%! And I think we need to get SQL server into involuntary rehab. Execution plans vs. slow version - http://imgur.com/eMzqPvL&zqQ6snz#0