# slow-running sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql like this, but it will run 17 seconds in the sqlserver. 
100 users logined my web to execute this sql at the same time just a moment ago (80% cpu usage), and it's ok.But it will over 1000 users tomorrow. 
so, my question is :
1: how to optimized this sql ?
2: 100 users 80% cpu usage, what will be happened if 1000users?

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
WITH tempQuestion AS
(
  SELECT 
    DISTINCT(CASE
      WHEN qut.IsComplex=1 THEN qf.Id
      WHEN qut.IsComplex=0 THEN qs.Id END) AS QuestionId,
    (CASE
      WHEN qut.IsComplex=1 THEN qf.Content
      WHEN qut.IsComplex=0 THEN qs.Content END) AS QuestionContent,
    (CASE
      WHEN qut.IsComplex=1 THEN qf.Content
      WHEN qut.IsComplex=0 THEN qs.Content END) AS QuetionContentOri,
    qut.IsComplex AS IsComplex, 
    qut.Id AS QuestionTemplateId,
    qut.Name AS QuestionTemplateName,
    qp.KnowDotCode AS KnowDotCode,
    (CASE
      WHEN qs.QuestionFaceCode IS NULL THEN qp.Analysis
      WHEN qs.QuestionFaceCode IS NOT NULL THEN '' END) AS Analyze,
    (CASE
      WHEN qs.QuestionFaceCode IS NULL THEN qp.SuitNumber
      WHEN qs.QuestionFaceCode IS NOT NULL THEN '' END) AS SuitNumber,
    (CASE
      WHEN qs.QuestionFaceCode IS NULL THEN qp.Difficult
      WHEN qs.QuestionFaceCode IS NOT NULL THEN '' END) AS Difficult,
    (CASE
      WHEN qs.QuestionFaceCode IS NULL THEN qp.Levels
      WHEN qs.QuestionFaceCode IS NOT NULL THEN '' END) AS Levels,
    (CASE
      WHEN qs.QuestionFaceCode IS NULL THEN qp.Exposure
      WHEN qs.QuestionFaceCode IS NOT NULL THEN '' END) AS Exposure,
--qp.Analysis AS Analyze,--浼氬鑷村鍚堥閲嶅
    qs.Tag,
    qc.Name AS QuestionCategoryName,
    qu.Name AS UnitName,
    qu.Name AS QuestionUnitName,
    qu.Id AS UnitId,
    qp.Fettle,
    (CASE
      WHEN qut.IsComplex=1 THEN ''
      WHEN qut.IsComplex=0 THEN qp.CreatedDateTime END) AS CreatedDateTime,
    (CASE
      WHEN qut.IsComplex=1 THEN ''
      WHEN qut.IsComplex=0 THEN qp.LastUseDateTime END) AS LastUseDateTime,
    (CASE
      WHEN qut.IsComplex=1 THEN ''
      WHEN qut.IsComplex=0 THEN u.Name END) AS CreateName,
    pqs.Id,
    pqs.OrderInPaper,
    pqs.Score as Point,
    pqs.PaperStrategyId,
    pqs.QuestionCategoryId,
    pqs.QuestionUnitId,
    pqs.KnowDotIds,
    (CASE
      WHEN qs.QuestionFaceCode IS NULL THEN   qs.Answer
      WHEN qs.QuestionFaceCode IS NOT NULL THEN('') END) AS CorrectAnswer 
  FROM EL_QuestionBank.QS_QuestionStem AS qs
    LEFT JOIN EL_QuestionBank.QS_QuestionFace AS qf
      ON qs.QuestionFaceCode=qf.Id
    INNER JOIN EL_QuestionBank.QS_QuestionProperty AS qp
      ON qp.QuestionStemCode=qs.Id
    LEFT JOIN EL_Organization.[User] AS u 
      ON qp.CreatorCode=u.Id
    INNER JOIN EL_QuestionBank.QuestionCategory AS qc
      ON qc.Id = qp.SubjectCode
    INNER JOIN EL_QuestionBank.QS_QuestionUnit AS qu
      ON qu.Id = qp.QuestionUnitCode
    INNER JOIN EL_QuestionBank.QS_QuestionUnitTemplate AS qut 
      ON qut.Id = qu.QuestionUnitTemplateCode
    INNER JOIN EL_Paper.PaperQuestionStrategy AS pqs
      ON ((qut.IsComplex=0 AND pqs.QuestionId=qs.Id) OR (qut.IsComplex=1 AND pqs.QuestionId=qf.Id))
   WHERE pqs.PaperStrategyId='576222efa335483680e4e2e6e1c3d254' 
)
SELECT * FROM tempQuestion
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Is Distinct really needed after having this many columns.

Comment: @Pradeep, yes, it's really needed.

Comment: why do you need WITH here? what did query execution plan show ?

Comment: Did you have a look at the execution plan? This usually gives you a good idea where you suffer the most.

Comment: I hope "qut.IsComplex" is bit type. so instead of having two 'when' inside 'case statements' remove the second 'when' and keep 'else' in all the 'case statements' same thing goes with "qs.QuestionFaceCode" it is doing null or not null check.

Comment: Can we assume you already gone over your indexes to see that they support your joins?

Comment: Maybe try to split up the last join with PaperQuestionStrategy, which uses an OR in the ON clause, to two joins!
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662555/can-i-make-this-join-using-or-faster-without-using-unions/26662710 for a similiar performance problem with OR in the ON clause.

Comment: @RADAR,@JamesBlond,my plan show is here: http://static.sjpxw.com.cn/Images/plan.png

Comment: my plan: http://static.sjpxw.com.cn/Images/plan.png

Comment: yes, i have indexed, @hatchet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try replacing

```
 INNER JOIN EL_Paper.PaperQuestionStrategy AS pqs 
    ON ((qut.IsComplex=0 AND  pqs.QuestionId=qs.Id) OR ( qut.IsComplex=1 AND pqs.QuestionId=qf.Id))
```

with

```
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM EL_Paper.PaperQuestionStrategy pqs1
             WHERE (qut.IsComplex=0 AND  pqs1.QuestionId=qs.Id)
             UNION ALL
             SELECT * FROM EL_Paper.PaperQuestionStrategy pqs2
             (qut.IsComplex=1 AND pqs2.QuestionId=qf.Id)
             ) AS pqs
```

This isn't guaranteed to speed it up, but I have run into cases in the past where I've seen performance of non-trivial queries improved by replacing OR conditions with use of UNION ALL. If this could have fit as a comment, I would have preferred to suggest it that way, since it's not a definitive answer. If you try it, add a comment telling whether it helped, hurt, or made no difference. Also, this is off the top of my head, so be sure to test that results are identical as well.

For folks applying this technique to similar situations, note that you may need to use `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL` to give the exact same results as the code you're replacing. In this case, the two selects being unioned are mutually exclusive since one can only contain rows with `IsComplex=0`, and the other can only contain rows with `IsComplex=1`, so `UNION ALL` works well. `UNION ALL` will typically be faster than `UNION`, but you can't choose based on the criteria of performance alone. You have to pick the the one that will produce the results you expect.

Comment: You should still be looking for ways to remove "select distinct" from your query, as hatchet observes this use of cross apply is only one step in optimizing the overall query.